# Is it possible to fudge the constructor of WebView with my new Context instead of original Application Context?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-context

I want a helper class to evaluate javascript with WebView:

```
public class EvaluateHelper {
    public static String evaluate(String st){
        WebView w;
        String result;
        //something code to evaluate javascript using WebView;
        return result;
    }
}
```

But the creation of web view needs a context, I want this class self-contained and do not want to modify other activity class to provide a context, I tried some methods:

1. fulfil with null

   WebView w=new WebView(null);
2. fulfil with new Activity

   WebView w=new WebView(new Activity());
3. fulfil with context in new Application

   WebView w=new WebView(new Application().getApplicationContext());
4. create custom child class from context, then provide my custom class for WebView:

   ```
   class MyContext extends Context{
       //some override method
   }

   WebView w=new WebView(new MyContext());
   ```

but they cause failed to run the app. Is there other way that create a WebView with my Context instead of app original Context? If not, is it possible to make this class self-contained?

Comment: For what purpose - what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this library from Square for running javascript

## **[`duktape-android` from Square](https://github.com/square/duktape-android)**